How to Add a Pre-Login Page in Keycloak for Tenant Identification Before Redirecting to the correct Login Page?
I am using Keycloak for authentication in a multi-tenant application. My requirement is to add a pre-login page where the user can provide their email, username, or tenant identifier. Based on this input:
Validate the input (e.g., check if the email is valid or belongs to a specific tenant).
Redirect the user to the appropriate tenant-specific login page (e.g., login-1 for Tenant A, login-2 for Tenant B).
For example:
A user enters their email user@tenantA.com on the pre-login page.
The system identifies this as belonging to Tenant A.
The user is redirected to Tenant A’s login page (login-1).
I’ve explored using Keycloak’s Identity Provider Redirector, but it seems to work only after submitting login credentials. Can I configure Keycloak to display a pre-login page within the authentication flow, or is there another way to achieve this? If a custom authenticator is required, what would the setup look like?

I also used keycloak for our multi-tenant application and I used custom theme for each tenant. my tenant is equivalent to a client.
may I know what the design is in your keycloak? is one tenant equivalent to a client or is it by realm?
